# Rails API not returning JSON to React frontend

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, api

I have written a Rails API backend. I can see that the endpoint is getting hit by watching my server in my terminal. I can also see a return in Postman. However, I am unable to get a payload returned in my React frontend. Here is my fetch call in React(I have the debuggers in there but they're not getting hit):

```
  handleSearch(video) {
   fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/search?q=${video}`)
    .then((response) => {
      debugger
      return response.json()
    })
    .then((data) => {
      debugger
    })
  }
```

Here is my api controller:

```
def index
    videos = VideoService.search_content(params['q'])
    render json: videos
  end
```

And here's my output in my terminal server:

```
Started GET "/api/v1/search?q=Firefly" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-28 11:40:38 -0700
Processing by Api::V1::SearchController#index as */*
  Parameters: {"q"=>"Firefly"}
Completed 200 OK in 426ms (Views: 7.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I'm not really sure what the problem is. I have never had an issue before when making api requests. And like I said. I can see the server being interacted with and can see a payload return in Postman. Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:**
Here is how I'm calling the handleSearch on the way down:

```
<SideBar
        info={this.state.info}
        logout={this.handleLogout.bind(this)}
        search={this.handleSearch.bind(this)}
       />
```

And here it is being called in the `SideBar` component:

```
searchHandler(video) {
    this.props.search(video)
  }

        <SearchBox search={this.searchHandler.bind(this)}/>
```

And finally where the input is actually coming in:

```
 handleSearch(e){
    let video = e.target.previousSibling.value
    this.props.search(video)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <form className="search-box" >
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search"/>
      <button className="fa fa-search" type="submit" onClick={this.handleSearch.bind(this)}>
      </button>
      </form>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Have you seen any errors in the console? If you're getting a payload with Postman and your controller action is returning 200, it seems like the error could be coming from your JavaScript somewhere. Everything else seems ok to me.

Comment: How are you calling the handleSearch method?

Comment: I pass the handleSearch in props to the button/input field in another components, which then returns the search term to this function. @PatrickHund

Comment: @DerekHopper, I'm not getting any errors in the console.

Comment: Try adding a catch method call to your fetch result and see if the debugger hits that

Comment: @DerekHopper nope, still no hits. I got excited there for a second, :P

Comment: Can you share the line of code where you've attached the `handleSearch` method? Just wondering if the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @PatrickHund sorry that last @ was meant for you. :P DerekHopper I've added where I'm calling it.

Comment: @charlietfl are you reffering to the first `handleSearch()` function or the last one. I kept the naming similar

Comment: Did you enable CORS in Rails to let your webapp talk through the browser to your api? Like https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/4d7f12b213-rails-5-api-and-cors

Comment: @CarlosC I did. That was a fun rabbit hole :P It turned out to be that I forgot to add preventDefault :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `e.preventDefault()` I'm new to React and thought it was handled behind the scenes by React.

Comment: Ah, interesting, I may have stumbled into that trap sooner or later myself 